# Mongoskin cursor on aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I am using mongoskin in nodejs for db queries.
I am not able to use cursor on aggregate query whereas in case of find query it is working fine.

```
    //This code is working fine
    var cursor = db.collection('users').find();
    cursor.forEach(function(user){
    console.log(user);
    }) 

    //The below query is not working
    var cursor = db.collection('users').aggregate([{$sort:{username:1}}]);
    cursor.forEach(function(user){
    console.log(user);
    }) 
    //error - cursor.forEach is not a function
```

Is there any alternate way of using a cursor on aggregation using mongoskin?
"mongoskin": "^2.1.0"

Comment: Which version of mongoskin are you using?

Comment: 2.1.0 @SurjeetBhadauriya

Comment: Use something like this let res= await db.collection('users').aggregate([{$sort:{username:1}}]).cursor({}).exec().toArray()

Comment: It is not working.I think this is a native mongo query.

Comment: This works in Node as well. BTW what error is it showing now?

Comment: db.collection(...).aggregate(...).cursor is not a function

Comment: Try with callback: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_1and2_2.html#aggregation-framework-helper

Comment: This works with native mongo(mongoClient). It does not work with mongoskin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. i created a library for it. which allows to write foreach with aggregate and could run with cursor. [mongoskin-cursor](https://github.com/miralbhalani/mongoskin-cursor)

> Example: db.collection('collectionname').aggregate().forEach(function(){});
>   db.collection('collectionname').aggregateAsync().then(function(){});